# Break for loop to call synchronous web services in swift

Tags: ios, swift2

I want to stop calling web services in the loop, once it will get status failed in any of the stages.

I have tried with below code but it seems all web service call make a queue and will call after that. I want to break loop immediately if any of web service call return fail.

```
//Call web services in loop
    for Prop: Property in self.properties!
    { 
        self.netUtil.callPostWebservice(unitUrl) {(dataDictionary) -> Void in
            let status = dataDictionary[self.constants!.defaultsKeys.RESPONSE_STATUS]
            if(status!.isEmpty || status==“FAIL”){
                break
            }
        }
    }

//Web service common function    
    func callPostWebservice(urlStr: String, callback: ((data: Dictionary<String,String>) -> Void)!)
    {
        let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlStr)!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.timeoutInterval = 20000.0

        var dict = Dictionary<String,String>()
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)

        if error == nil{
            if data == nil{
                dict[self.constants.defaultsKeys.RESPONSE_STATUS] = self.constants.defaultsKeys.RESPONSE_FAIL
                callback(data:  dict)
            }
            else{

                dict[self.constants.defaultsKeys.RESPONSE_STATUS] = self.constants.defaultsKeys.RESPONSE_SUCCESS
                callback(data:  dict)

            }
        }
        else{dict[self.constants.defaultsKeys.RESPONSE_STATUS] = self.constants.defaultsKeys.RESPONSE_FAIL
            callback(data:  dict)
        }

        })
        task.resume()

    }
```

Comment: I guess you should call perform selector / dispatch functiopn to call web service. Once you will get response success from first webservice then again call same function using  perform selector / dispatch functiopn and in case of fail don't call webservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because API behaviour is `async` and you for loop works in `sync` manner. To solve your issue you can try something like this.

```
func getData() {
    if (cnt < self.properties.count) {
        let prop: Property = self.properties[cnt]
        self.netUtil.callPostWebservice(unitUrl) {(dataDictionary) -> Void in
            let status = dataDictionary[self.constants!.defaultsKeys.RESPONSE_STATUS]
            if(status.isEmpty || status!=“FAIL”){
            {
                cnt++
                self.getData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now create on `cnt` var of `Int` type and call this method like this way

```
cnt = 0
self.getData()
```